# Python connection to solid db

Tags: python, ibm-soliddb

i must make a connection to solid db from python. Do you know any module, library or a method which can create a connection to Solid DB follow by a SQL query?

Answer (score 0):

Solid DB has ODBC drivers so you can use PyODBC: http://mkleehammer.github.io/pyodbc/